# Can I customize battle.net games in laucher sidebar?

Tags: battle.net

I use battle.net launcher to play Starcraft 2 and HearthStone. I want to remove Diablo and WoW from the the list, or at least reorder the list, so I can move it to bottom. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

You can't remove the games from the sidebar, but you can reorder them. Either drag and drop the games to the order that you want or right click and select move up / move down.